# как хранить данные в памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x

в общем учусь писать красивые gui для python приложений с помощью либы `eel`.Получаю данные `sql` запросом они отображаются. Теперь хочу по ссылке переходить на другую страницу с более подробной информацией. С этим тоже все понятно. Дальше со страницы с подробной информацией хочу осуществить переход обратно. Но теперь после перехода все данные с инфой не остаются на первоначальной странице. Как можно организовать их сохранение , до того как не выполнится другой `sql` запрос.
шаблон получаю с помощью jinja2
в функции возвращаю так

```
def test_list(p1,p2,p3):
    html_tab = template.render(
    worker = name,
    rows_1=[k for k, v in time_work.items()],
    rows_2=a,
    rows_3=[v[0][1] for k, v in time_work.items()],
    rows_4=[v[-1][-1] for k, v in time_work.items()],
    )
    return html_tab
```

и потом с помощью js вывожу в `div`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    async function display_graph(){

        let personnel_number =document.getElementById('worker').value; 
        let start_date =document.getElementById('start').value; 
        let end_date =document.getElementById('end').value; 
        let res =await eel.test_list(personnel_number,start_date,end_date)();
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;

    }

    jQuery('#show').on('click',function(){
        display_graph();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - у вас питон является веб-сервером и gui в браузере? в таком случае не выйдет. gui в браузере == потеря контекста.

Comment: Ну можно, например, в json в файле данные сохранить. Главное чтобы вы как-то могли понять, что вы вернулись на страницу, а не только что на неё пришли. Кэширование - непростая тема, не видя, как у вас там всё устроено, сложно советовать.

Comment: @CrazyElf не знаю что еще добавить можно. Добавил часть кода в вопрос